# Get a file without name in url

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to get the file from this url : https://donnees.roulez-eco.fr/opendata/instantane

As you can see there's no file name in the URL.

My problem is with this simple code :

```
var file = fs.createWriteStream('./myFile.zip')
http.get(url, function(response) {
    response.pipe(file);
}
```

This code works well if you got an url like https://someurl.com/filename.zip.

The file is downloaded and can be use but this `response.pipe(file)` line throw me this error:

events.js:163

```
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: Parse Error
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:411:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:178:18)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:136:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:559:20)
```

What should / can i do to fix this?

Comment: The URL is entirely arbitrary here, there's no correlation to the file. If you're getting a "parse error" then something is wrong with the response. Test with `curl` if you can to be sure the URL is working as you expect. Checking the response code is also not a bad idea.

Comment: I just randomly tested somthing. With a "/" at the end of the url it works well. I've lost too much time on this dumb error :/ thank for the reply.